# Why is my IF statement not evaulataing.. New to Python

Tags: python

Not sure why the IF statements aren't evaluating correctly. I am taking a python class and I think it's due to strings being compared. Not sure. I know SQL well but new to python... I test the results with 1 household and 200000 income which should come out as Moderate Income but its writing all print statements.

```
#capture number of people in the household
Householdtotal = input("Please enter the total amount of people in your household:")
time.sleep(.5)
print("Thank you")
print("")

#capture total household income
HouseholdtotalIncome = input("Please enter your combined household income:")
time.sleep(.5)
print("Thank you")
print("")

if Householdtotal < '1':
    print("You must enter a value greater than 1")
print("")




#Extremely Low 
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= "31050" and Householdtotal <= "1" :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Extremely Low Income (30% or lower)")  
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '35500' and Householdtotal <= '2' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Extremely Low Income (30% or lower)")  

if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '44350' and Householdtotal == '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Extremely Low Income (30% or lower)") 
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '44350' and Householdtotal > '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Extremely Low Income (30% or lower)")  


    
 #Very Low Income   
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '51800' and Householdtotal == "1" :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Very Low Income (50% or lower)")   
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '51800' and Householdtotal == '2' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Very Low Income (50% or lower)")   

if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '73950' and Householdtotal == '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Very Low Income (50% or lower)") 
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '73950' and Householdtotal > '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Very Low Income (50% or lower)")   

    
#Low Income
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '78550' and Householdtotal == "1":
    print("Your Income is categorized as Low Income (80% or lower)")  
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '89750' and Householdtotal == '2' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Low Income (80% or lower)")    

if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '112150' and Householdtotal == '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Low Income (80% or lower)")   
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '112150' and Householdtotal > '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Low Income (80% or lower)") 
    
    
#Median Income
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '103550' and Householdtotal == "1" :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Median Income (100% or lower)")  
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '118300' and Householdtotal == '2' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Median Income (100% or lower)")    

if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '147900' and Householdtotal == '4' :
   print("Your Income is categorized as Median Income (100% or lower)")

if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '147900' and Householdtotal > '4' :
   print("Your Income is categorized as Median Income (100% or lower)") 


#Moderate Income
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '124250' and Householdtotal == "1" :
     print("Your Income is categorized as Moderate Income (120% or lower)")  
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '142000' and Householdtotal == '2' :
     print("Your Income is categorized as Moderate Income (120% or lower)")    

if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '177500' and Householdtotal == '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Moderate Income (120% or lower)")
    
if HouseholdtotalIncome <= '177500' and Householdtotal > '4' :
    print("Your Income is categorized as Moderate Income (120% or lower)")
    


print("")
time.sleep(.5)
print("Good Bye")
```

Comment: `200000` is not moderate income.

Comment: Yeah, comparing strings probably doesn't work as you think. Read the input as *number* and compare numbers. See the duplicate linked above.

Comment: @blhsing Depends on the currency.

Comment: @deceze I mean, according to the logics of the OP's code, after fixing the type issue.

Comment: The problem is you're comparing the numbers as strings, which is an _alphabetic_ comparison, not a _numeric_ comparison.